# Date Pattern for 22/10/18 - 3:05pm - java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: need help identifying correct date pattern

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert String to timestamp, but getting a parse error for date pattern.

```
String timeString= "22/10/18 - 3:05pm";
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/mm/yy - h:mma", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(timeString, format);
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(datetime);
System.out.println(timestamp);
```

Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '22/10/18 - 3:05pm' could not be parsed at index 13

Comment: Hmm `mm` looks like `mm`

Comment: By the way, when calling [`Timestamp.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf(java.time.LocalDateTime)), be aware that the current default time zone of the JVM at runtime is being implicitly applied to that `LocalDateTime` when instantiating the `Timestamp` object. I recommend applying your intended/expected time zone explicitly to the `LocalDateTime` to get an `Instant`, and pass to [`Timestamp.from`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html#from(java.time.Instant)).

Answer (score 3):

Use Uppercase for PM and of course month should be `MM`

```
String timeString= "22/10/18 - 3:05PM";
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy - h:mma", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(timeString, format);
```

Comment: How do I accommodate "2/10/18 - :01am" format too, in my file 12'o clock has no hour value displayed, so I end up getting below error: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2/10/18 - :01AM' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 0